# Operation right nodes smaller and left nodes bigger

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I need to write operation that return true if the right nodes are smaller than the Head and the left nodes are Bigger than the Head. I tried to check it but it return false every time.

```
public static bool IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(BinNode<int> Head)
    {
        if (Head == null)
            return false; // no leaves and no parent.

        if (IsLeaf(Head))
            return false; // head is a leaf, so there is no parent.

        var right = Head.GetRight();
        var left = Head.GetLeft();

        if (left != null)
        {
            if (left.GetValue() < Head.GetValue())
                return true;
            else if (!IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(left))
                return false;
        }
        if (right != null)
        {
            if (right.GetValue() > Head.GetValue())
                return true;
            else if (!IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(right))
                return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Tried again but when its arrived to the leaves it return false:

```
public static bool IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(BinNode<int> Head)
    {
        if (Head == null)
            return false; // no leaves and no parent ~null~.

        var right = Head.GetRight();
        var left = Head.GetLeft();
        if (left == null && right == null)
            return false;
        if (left == null && right != null)
            return IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(right);
        if (left != null && right == null)
            return IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(left);
        if (left != null && right != null)
        {
            if (left.GetValue() > Head.GetValue() && right.GetValue() < Head.GetValue())
            {
                return IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(left) && IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(right);
            }
        }

            return false;

    }
```

Comment: its not for the test , i do it to know better the matriel

Comment: If one call to `IsRightSmallANDLeftBig` returns `false`, all the recursion tree will return `false`.

Comment: @Guy can you please write the code?

Comment: I don't have the time right now and you won't learn anything if you won't do it yourself. Use the debugger and go step by step to see what exactly the method does and how it is different from what you expect.

Comment: The main issue is the code that returns `false` for leaf nodes, which is causing the parent call also to return `false`. So you should remove that code (because it's handled by `null` checks later) or change it to return `true`. This will solve the *always return false* issue. But there are other bugs in that code - check the inner `if`s that return `true` - they should actually return `false`.

Comment: @IvanStoev see the edited code , I tried with new way , but when I arrive to the leaves it return false , what can i do? please help:)

Comment: **Don't** return `false` when `left == null && right == null`, it's the same as your original code. You need basically `return (right == null || (right.GetValue() < Head.GetValue() && IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(right)))
    && (left == null || (left.GetValue() > Head.GetValue() && IsRightSmallANDLeftBig(left)));`. Hope you can understand it.

Comment: you awesome , thank you very much!